# SSRS _ sum of conditions

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to sum this

```
=IIF(IIF(Fields!Allocation.Value="Y",
SUM(IIf(Fields!Allocation.Value = "Y", 1, 0), "TargetLetter1") * Format(Fields!Kpi_Weight.Value, "N")
,SUM(IIf(Fields!Allocation.Value = "X", 1, 0), "TargetLetter1") * Format(Fields!Kpi_Weight.Value, "N")) >= 1, "100%"
, FormatPercent(IIF(Fields!Allocation.Value="Ranking",
SUM(IIf(Fields!Allocation.Value = "Y", 1, 0), "TargetLetter1") * Format(Fields!Kpi_Weight.Value, "N")
,SUM(IIf(Fields!Allocation.Value = "X", 1, 0), "TargetLetter1") * Format(Fields!Kpi_Weight.Value, "N")), 2))
```

but it throws error.

Can you help?

Comment: what error do you get. Also can you do one step at a time. I mean just take `SUM(IIf(Fields!Allocation.Value = "Y", 1, 0), "TargetLetter1") * Format(Fields!Kpi_Weight.Value, "N")` and see if it returns correct data. so you can narrow it down easily

Comment: As AnkUser has asked, can you edit your question and post the error. I would also suggest you do not format the output in the expression but rather format t the text box as this will make finding the error easier.

Comment: The syntax looks OK. If you run it in Visual Studio, it usually gives a somewhat better error message.